# ImageResizer.NET - too many images in imagecache folder

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer.NET (with diskcache plugin) and its awesome

DiskCache plugin is initialized as documentation says, with default options:`<add name="DiskCache" />` ... no other confuguration, just defaults

I assumed defaults are: `subfolders="32"` and `maximumItemsPerFolder="1000"`

The problem is: 
- in each folder (in imagecache folder) i have more than 3000 images, not only 1000, so my disk space is not enough to hadle this number of cached images

Questions are :

1. Am i doing something wrong with default configuration (i assume it should be 32 folders x max 1000 images=32 000 cached images maximum)
2. Or, how to limit each folder in imagecache to have maximum 1000 last added images

Comment: Can you paste your diagnostics page into a Gist? Did you set autoClean="true"?

Comment: No, did not set autoclean="true", but when i tried to run resizer.debug.ashx, as i did before, i have seen message: The Resizer diagnostics page is only available from localhost.

This is because <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />.

To override for localhost access, add <diagnostics enableFor="localhost" /> in the <resizer> section of Web.config.

To ovveride for remote access, add <diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" /> in the <resizer> section of Web.config. in fact i set in web.config:<customErrors mode="On"/>

Comment: Ok, just seen documentation, will change web.config and send diagnostics page to gist

Comment: ok, here are diagnostics : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6dd8e4cf0da0edf8903

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable cache cleanup; by [default it is disabled](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache).

`<diskcache autoClean="true" />`

> autoClean
>
> When true, will keep a background thread running to 'clean' unused items from the disk cache. This background thread uses smart 'activity
> sensing' to avoid doing cleanup work when the site is busy. Defaults
> to false, since the cleanup system is still in beta.

Comment: Thanks for response, but before i try this, do i need to manualy delete 2GB of old images in imagecache, or "autoclean" will do then job?

Comment: Anytime you change the value for 'subfolders', you will need to manually delete them. If it hasn't changed, then autoclean could do it for you. But renaming the folder, then deleting it after an app pool recycle is certainly the fastest way.

Comment: @user2981411 https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1749/Imagemagick.html  
It's also very slow. If you're paying for a server, you'll be wasting both time and money.